# Bolnagri (Devanagiri/Hindi) Input method

Tags: input-method

There is a particular input method for Hindi language (or Devanagiri script), known as Bolnagri. It is very convenient to type using this method and it comes by default on Ubuntu.

However, in Emacs, there are 4 input methods for typing in Devanagiri, but none of them is Bolnagri. That is when I press `C-x RET C-\`, I don't see any "Bolnagri" in the options.

How can I get this Bolnagri input method to work in Emacs?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.emacs/VI53dIhXCe0 and https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SupportHindi could be relevant.

Comment: What is the output of M-x list-input-methods?

Comment: @ArunKumarKhattri `M-x list-input-methods` shows 4 Devanagiri input methods (among other languages): `devanagari-inscript`, `devanagari-aiba`, `devanagari-kyoto-harvard`, `devanagari-itrans`.

Comment: If someone can produce a list of the mappings between ASCII input and the desired devanagari codepoints, that would be pretty easy to turn into an  input method. There are screenshots on the indlinux page, but they're hard to turn into Unicode :-)

Comment: @rpluim in debian linux the keymap is defined in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/in` which is available in the package `xkb-data`: https://packages.debian.org/buster/xkb-data .. there you can see the unicode

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not there (yet)...  There are email addresses on the IndLinux page for BolNagri https://indlinux.org/wiki/index.php/BolNagri, perhaps an author there might assist with porting it to an emacs input method.

However, you can always use the system input method (in my case on Linux xkb) with emacs.

In Linux/KDE it is possible to map switching input methods to `Ctrl+Super+k`, as this does not interfere with an emacs binding.  How this is done, is [described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275639/how-do-i-temporarily-switch-between-keyboards-on-kde-plasma-5).  This is, indeed, not ideal, as we would strife for a environment independent solution within emacs. So someone needs to sit down and port BolNagri to emacs...

A downside from the system input is, that the emacs key combinations don't work.  For example, if you press `Ctrl+C` emacs will register the `Ctrl+छ`, and the commands won't work as usual.  Thus, having a real BolNagri input method is desired.